# referencing a blob via a File object

Tags: java, file, google-app-engine, blob

Is there any way I can refer the *blob* in the blobstore via a `File` object ? I have the blob key.Now how do I refer the blob there ?

```
// Let the blob key be 'squuheaeinlie'
File blobReference = new File(...?....);
```

I am actually referring a xml file which is a blob. I want to read and write to that xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access blobstore blobs as files (not as a true `File`, but close) via [`AppEngineFile`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/AppEngineFile).

Here's a full example on how to [write and read blobs via this API.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore)

**Edit:** You can load an existing blob via a blob-key:

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(blob-key); 
FileReadChannel channel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, false);
// now read from channel
```

Comment: I looked at the documentation of _AppEngineFile_.One of the constructor accepts the _File_ path to the blobstore. How do I give the path ? Just put the key inside the constructor ? And the example you cited doesn't show any snippet to read the file from the store

Comment: Added an example how to load `AppEngineFile` via a blob key.

Comment: I want to see the xml file read from the blobstore as xml file in the browser.[I am reading the data into the ByteBuffer from the channel,but what to do after that ? How to present it is there in the store](http://i48.tinypic.com/2v0hes0.png)

Comment: Just serving a blob to browser is easy: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob

Comment: just serving using that won't solve the purpose ! I have to parse that file _(xml)_,append some data to it and save that file back.

Comment: Though `AppEngineFile` and `File` are two different classes , can I cast _AppEngineFile_ object to _File_ object where _File_ is necessary ? For example I needed to write to to blob which is a xml file. For example [javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder#parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.io.File))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16028/discussion-between-suhail-gupta-and-peter-knego)

Comment: I managed to write the code that updates the xml there in  the blobstore but there is one problem. If can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212424/xml-file-doesnt-update-what-is-the-reason-for-this