# xml file doesn't update. What is the reason for this?

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, blobstore

There is a *xml* file in the blobstore which looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Blobs>

</Blobs>
```

The following servlet uploads a file to the *blobstore*. After it uploads the file , it gets the *file* key and calls a Bean that updates the xml by adding a node whose text-content is the key.

```
public class UploadImagesToAisle extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path = request.getParameter("Data");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
     try {
       boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
       if( !isMultipart ) {
           writer.println("File cannot be uploaded !");
       }  else {
           ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
           FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
           List list = null;
           while(iter.hasNext()) {
               FileItemStream item = iter.next();
               String name  = item.getFieldName();
               String fileName = item.getName();
               String mimeType = new MimeType().getMimeType(fileName);
               if(mimeType == null) {
                   response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
               }
               InputStream stream = item.openStream();
               if(item.isFormField()) {
                   // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
               } else {
                   // Get a file service
                   FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
                   // Create a new Blob file with mime-type "text/plain"
                   AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(mimeType, fileName);
                   // Open a channel to write to it
                   boolean lock = true;
                   FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);
                   // copy byte stream from request to channel
                   byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                   int len;
                   while ((len = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, len));
                   }

                   writeChannel.closeFinally();

                   if(MimeType.isImage) {
                       String key = fileService.getBlobKey(file).getKeyString();
                       // update the xml file with the key
                       new UpdateXml().appendKey(key);  // BEAN CALLED
                   }

                   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("private/cpanel/PcPanel.jsp");
                   dispatcher.forward(request, response);
               }
           }
       }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        writer.println(exc);
    }
}
}
```

Following is a *Bean* that is called by the above servlet to update/write the *xml*.

```
public class UpdateXml {

private final String xmlKey = "AMIfv95NSB_FKs2v6o0dIKkSdmSIJVtE0oq9X4hyTbxOTglDi6XoDaTUBlXxa3OsPfDo8ZQZF8kFb059zg4kJ3lK2MlgudC_nkQdwCpx1kYP9Rwb40s0HClFzzIIUv-UtMbuycxixVtfw-fYyhC3MXvFc1Gh-Cv9mQ";

public void appendKey(String key) {
    try {
        FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
        AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile( new BlobKey( xmlKey ) );
        FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, true);
        InputStream stream = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(stream);
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        Element blobKey = doc.createElement("blob-key");
        blobKey.setTextContent(key);

        root.appendChild(blobKey);

        GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder();
        optionsBuilder.setBucket("my-bucket");
        optionsBuilder.setKey(xmlKey);
        optionsBuilder.setMimeType("text/html");
        optionsBuilder.setAcl("public_read");
        optionsBuilder.addUserMetadata("suhail", "gupta");

        AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());
        FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
        OutputStream output = Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source  = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING,"UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The file uploads fine,but an entry is not made to the xml file.There isn't any error log in the logs. I don't understand the reason for this. What is the problem ?

Comment: Try to add some log and a `else` for `if(mimeType.isImage()) {` **(note: I assumed the if needs correction)**

Comment: @RC. I have verified that `if` block is working every time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the file is not persisted because you forgot to finalize:

> append to it and when all done writing, you must finalize the file for it to persist

[Source](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService)

try adding: `writeChannel.closeFinally();` or `writeChannel.close()` after `transformer.transform(source, result);`

---

**EDIT**

You never write into `writableFile`:

```
FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
```

but try to write into file which is open as read and locked.

Comment: I tried but the same old thing.When I see the xml(from the blobstore) it is without any node added.

Comment: from the link you cited in your answer it says , to view the file to anybody on internet one can visit `http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/mybucket/myfile` and my link goes like http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/AMIfv95NSB_FKs2v6o0dIKkSdmSIJVtE0oq9X4hyTbxOTglDi6XoDaTUBlXxa3OsPfDo8ZQZF8kFb059zg4kJ3lK2MlgudC_nkQdwCpx1kYP9Rwb40s0HClFzzIIUv-UtMbuycxixVtfw-fYyhC3MXvFc1Gh-Cv9mQ but when I visit the page it says no such key. why is that

Comment: can you please comment on the issue ?

Comment: So I need to replace `file` with `writableFile` in the statement `fileService.openWriteChannel(...)` ?

Comment: "close" `file`, and write to `writableFile`, it should work if a file can be overwritten (I can't test as I don't have an appengine test environment on this computer)

Comment: I am still stuck. Can we discuss that here @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16153/discussion-between-rc-and-suhail-gupta